# Please correct my chinese "Today is my day"

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

Today is the Singles' day, so I want to say something like "Today is my day. I accept your congratulations". Sure, it's some kind of a joke.

Could you correct me, please, if I'm wrong:
今天我的日子！ 接受你们的祝贺。

Is this sounds ok? Or it's gonna sound strange for chinese people?

Comment: 今天是我的节日 or 我今天过节(more natural)

Comment: users suggest adapting ichacha results for＂my day" :  my lucky day    我的幸福纪念日,  my luck day    我的幸运日,not my day    运气不佳

Answer (score 1):

今天是我的日子 is not something a Chinese person would say, because it is a direct translation of an English colloquial phrase.

If you want to express your happiness on this day, you can say:

光棍节真是为我设计的 (Single's Day was created for me).

光棍节了真开心， 都来祝贺我啊~ (I am so happy that it is Single's Day. Everyone congratulate me).

These are informal ways of talking, which may have better results if you want to make a joke :)

Answer (score 0):

**今天是我的日子！**

**今天是我** *接受你们的祝贺的* **日子！** 。(the relative clause should be placed before the noun "日子"

However. “Today is my day” is a common English expression that means “Today is my lucky day” or “today is the day I success”. 
It would be "今天是我走運的一天" (today is my lucky day) or "今天是我吐氣揚眉的日子"(today is the day I success) in Chinese language.

"Singles' day is a day **for me**," is "單身日是**為我而設的**日子" or simply "單身日是我的日子" in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

今天是我XX的日子.

今天是我大喜的日子 (for wedding).

今天是我的幸运日.